# Collapse paths in a directed graph algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let's say there are 4 people: A, B, C and D.
A owes B \$100, B owes C \$75, C owes A \$10, C owes D \$85, and D owes B \$1.

That can be reduced to: A owes B \$26, A owes D \$64, and C owes D \$20.

(A owes B \$100 who owes C \$75, so A owes C \$75 and A owes B \$25. C owes A \$10, so on net A owes C \$65. C owes D \$85, so A owes D \$65 and C owes D \$20. D owes B \$1 so A owes B \$1 and A owes D \$64. In total A owes B \$25+\$1=\$26)

That sounded an awfully like one of those math programming questions I had in college and I thought it could be represented in a graph.

So my question is, is there an (already established) algorithm that can simplify this graph:
[image: graph1]

into this graph:

[image: graph2]

or do I have to just do it iteratively?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware that (without additional constraints) there is no unique solution.
In your own example $C$ could also pay 20 to $B$, $A$ pay 84 to $D$ and 6 to $B$.

I don't think you need a very smart algorithm here.
At every node you compute the net contribution (that can be positive or negative)
by summing the (directed) edge weights (e.g. at $B$ you would find $75-100-1=-26).
Then you arbitrarily pair up net receivers and net donators.
It depends a bit on how your graph and edge weights are represented,
but it is hard to do this wrong (in the sense of inefficient).

Btw. I would not call this an iterative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was wondering if this problem had a name. I suppose an inefficient algorithm could be, look for any paths with two steps, such as A->B->C, and then simplify it to any of the combinations of A->B, A->C, and B->C. So in this example, A->B is 100 and B->C is 75, so that simplifies to A->C 75, A->B 25, and B->C 0. And then repeat. I also found this link which seems to be the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts

Comment: The link in the last answer of the question you refer to has a rather exhaustive treatment of the problem with various additional constraints.